# Php PDO Datatable Llist json data list

Tags: php, json, pdo

DataTable no data

PHP codes

```
$db = new ...
$statement  = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sehirler");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo  json_encode($results);
```

PHP Code Result

```
{"ID":"25","Code":"34","City":"Antalya"}
```

Jquery Code

DataTable Link

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url : "data.php",
            method: "POSt"
        },
    } );
} );
```

Comment: your php code does not return the convoluted expected structure datatables needs. read the docs, which you have linked to, the structure is in the ajax tab

Answer (score 1):

On `Ajax` tab of [provided link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side), you can see what data format you should return from server.

So, you need to modify output from your script:

```
$db = new ...
$statement  = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sehirler");
$statement->execute();
// to get 0-indexed array use `PDO::FETCH_NUM` mode
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

echo  json_encode(array(
    'data' => $results,
    // Maybe following fields are optional
    //"draw" => 1,
    //"recordsTotal" => 57,
    //"recordsFiltered" =>57,
));
```